# Should I use "I'm noting down ..." or "I'm taking ... to note."?

Tags: grammaticality, idioms, phrasal-verbs, expression-choice

In this example, I am writing down in my notebook some high-level terms that were used in other people's conversation. I want to tell my friend that I am doing so. In the following two sentences, which should I use to express this to him?

I was thinking of using "noting down", like:

> I'm **noting down** the high-level terms used in John and David's conversation.

Or, should I use "taking *(other parts of the sentence here)* to note.", with:

> I'm **taking** the high-level terms used in John and David's conversation **to note**.

Which sentence is preferred? Or, are there any other more appropriate sentences?

Comment: Whichever one suits your style.

Comment: @HotLicks Do you have an answer to write?

Comment: I don't find _taking... to note_ idiomatic. You could use _taking notes on/of_.

Comment: You're *writing down* the terms. You could also be *taking note of* the terms or *noting* the terms, but that doesn't necessarily mean you're taking notes in writing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of the two sentences you suggest, I would use the first:
"I'm noting down the high-level terms used in John and David's conversation."

To my mind, your second option is not very clear because the words "I'm taking" and "to note" are too far apart and, consequently, the meaning of your sentence is not so clear.

Another option would be to write:
"I am taking note(s) of the high-level terms used in John and David's conversation."
But that is still longer than the first option and also - to my mind - less clear than your first option.